# SwiftUi ViewModel Not initializing all stored properties

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to pass data into a ViewModel and am getting a "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

Anything I do after init( entry:Entry ) in the ViewModel gets an error.

I am first passing the data in from a MainView like this:

```
struct MainView: View {

    @State var entry = Entry()

    // inputting the data
    TextField("Beg Value", text: self.$entry.a)

    // passing to next view
    NavigationLink(
         destination: ShowView( entry: entry ),   
         label: {Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise") }) 

}
```

This is the view that gets the data.

```
struct ShowView: View {
  
    var entry: Entry
 
    @ObservedObject var showVM: ShowViewModel

    init( entry:Entry  ) {
        self.entry = entry
        self.showVM = ShowViewModel( entry: entry  )
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel where I get the error after I initialize the data. I have tried many variants.

```
class ShowViewModel:  ObservableObject {
  
    var entry: Entry

    init(entry: Entry) {
        self.entry = entry
    }

   init(){
        print("here") \\ Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
   }

}
```

and the Entry Struct.  I have also tried as a class.

```
struct Entry  {

    var month: Date = Date()
    var a:String = "1"
    var b:String = "2"
    var c:String = "3"
    var d:String = "4"
    var e:String = "5"
    var f: String = ""
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the second init if you are not using it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove second `init` and make one with default value (to be used if not provided in arguments), like

```
class ShowViewModel:  ObservableObject {
  
    @Published var entry: Entry

    init(entry: Entry = Entry()) {
        self.entry = entry
    }

}
```

Comment: I cant do anything after this init.

Comment: What do you mean? Before you can't even compile. Most probably you need to add `@Published` (as you declared class ObservableObject)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

I guess you forgot to add NavigationView in the MainView and the Body is missing.

Also, Instead of @ObservedObject, you can use @Binding.

```
struct Entry  {
    var month: Date = Date()
    var a:String = "1"
    var b:String = "2"
    var c:String = "3"
    var d:String = "4"
    var e:String = "5"
    var f: String = ""
}

class ShowViewModel:  ObservableObject {
  
    var entry: Entry

    init(entry: Entry) {
        self.entry = entry
    }

}

struct ShowView: View {
  
    @ObservedObject var showVM: ShowViewModel

    init( entry:Entry  ) {
        self.showVM = ShowViewModel( entry: entry  )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(showVM.entry.a)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    @State var entry = Entry()
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                // inputting the data
                TextField("Beg Value", text: self.$entry.a)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                // passing to next view
                NavigationLink(
                     destination: ShowView( entry: entry ),
                     label: {Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise") })
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```